# laravel 5.4 - return post exact model in eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have a `Post` model and two `TextPost` and `PhotoPost` models extending from it.

I want to do something like `Post::find(1);` and if the record with `id=1` have `type=photo` attribute, it should return me an instance of `PhotoPost` model otherwise should be an instance of `TextPost` model. how can do this in laravel 5.4? my classes are as below:

Post.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['file_id', 'file', 'bot_id', 'text'];

    public function bot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Bot::class);
    }
}
```

TextPost.php

```
namespace App;

use App\Traits\TextPostTrait;

class TextPost extends Post
{
    use TextPostTrait;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = ['bot_id', 'text'];

    protected $attributes = ['type' => 'text'];

}
```

PhotoPost.php

```
namespace App;

use App\Traits\PhotoPostTrait;

class PhotoPost extends Post
{
    use PhotoPostTrait;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $attributes = ['type' => 'photo', 'image_watermark'];
```

}

PhotoPostTrait.php

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Scopes\PhotoPostScope;

trait PhotoPostTrait
{
    public static function bootPhotoPostTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new PhotoPostScope());
    }
}
```

TextPostTrait.php

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Scopes\TextPostScope;

trait TextPostTrait
{
    public static function bootSettingsTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new TextPostScope());
    }
}
```

TextPostScope.php

```
namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;

class TextPostScope implements ScopeInterface
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('type', 'text');
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
    }
}
```

PhotoPostTrait.php

```
namespace App\Scopes;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class PhotoPostScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('type', '=', 'photo');
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
    }
}
```

so I use globalScopes to categorize my post types. so basically I store them in a single table. so I should add the $table='posts'; so that laravel does not take it as a seperate model. and using traits to boot the scope. and inside the scopes I will make sure the record is a `Photo` or a `Text`.

***EDIT***

**I found a solution by JarekTkaczyk at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/multiple-models-to-same-table
But I want to know does laravel a native solution for this problem?**

Comment: shouldn't you be using a morph attribute instead of this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: its close but I cant figure it out how can use this morph feature to make different types of post.